# HP LaserJet Pro MFP m26nw won't print as a network printer on Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, printing, printer, hplip

I can get it working over USB, but we really want this on the network.

The printer is an HP LaserJet Pro MFP m26nw, the OS is Mint 19.1 64 bit Mate.

After installing, the test page job changes to a "stopped" status and an error pops up that says, "there was a problem processing document 'test page'".

Here's the log output:

```
Feb 12 14:27:01 desktop systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Feb 12 15:15:36 desktop /hpfax[5157]: [5157]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
Feb 12 15:16:48 desktop hpcups[5243]: prnt/hpcups/Hbpl1.cpp 52: Hbpl1 constructor : m_szLanguage = HBPL1
Feb 12 15:16:48 desktop hpcups[5243]: common/utils.c 69: unable to open /var/lib/hp/hplip.state: No such file or directory
Feb 12 15:16:48 desktop hpcups[5243]: common/utils.c 119: validate_plugin_version() Failed to get Plugin version from [/var/lib/hp/hplip.state]
Feb 12 15:16:48 desktop hpcups[5243]: common/utils.c 157: Plugin version is not matching
Feb 12 15:16:48 desktop hpcups[5243]: prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 486: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
Feb 12 15:17:53 desktop hpcups[5372]: prnt/hpcups/Hbpl1.cpp 52: Hbpl1 constructor : m_szLanguage = HBPL1
Feb 12 15:17:53 desktop hpcups[5372]: common/utils.c 69: unable to open /var/lib/hp/hplip.state: No such file or directory
Feb 12 15:17:53 desktop hpcups[5372]: common/utils.c 119: validate_plugin_version() Failed to get Plugin version from [/var/lib/hp/hplip.state]
Feb 12 15:17:53 desktop hpcups[5372]: common/utils.c 157: Plugin version is not matching
Feb 12 15:17:53 desktop hpcups[5372]: prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 486: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
Feb 12 15:18:47 desktop systemd[1]: cups.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 12 15:18:47 desktop systemd[1]: cups.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 12 15:18:47 desktop systemd[1]: cups.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 12 15:18:47 desktop systemd[1]: cups.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Feb 12 15:19:04 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Feb 12 15:19:04 desktop systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Feb 12 15:27:16 desktop /hpfax[5506]: [5506]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
Feb 12 15:33:35 desktop hpcups[5677]: prnt/hpcups/Hbpl1.cpp 52: Hbpl1 constructor : m_szLanguage = HBPL1
Feb 12 15:33:35 desktop hpcups[5677]: common/utils.c 69: unable to open /var/lib/hp/hplip.state: No such file or directory
Feb 12 15:33:35 desktop hpcups[5677]: common/utils.c 119: validate_plugin_version() Failed to get Plugin version from [/var/lib/hp/hplip.state]
Feb 12 15:33:35 desktop hpcups[5677]: common/utils.c 157: Plugin version is not matching
Feb 12 15:33:35 desktop hpcups[5677]: prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 486: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
Feb 12 15:33:35 desktop hp[5678]: prnt/backend/hp.c 919: ERROR: null print job total=0
Feb 12 15:33:56 desktop hpcups[5690]: prnt/hpcups/Hbpl1.cpp 52: Hbpl1 constructor : m_szLanguage = HBPL1
Feb 12 15:33:56 desktop hpcups[5690]: common/utils.c 69: unable to open /var/lib/hp/hplip.state: No such file or directory
Feb 12 15:33:56 desktop hpcups[5690]: common/utils.c 119: validate_plugin_version() Failed to get Plugin version from [/var/lib/hp/hplip.state]
Feb 12 15:33:56 desktop hpcups[5690]: common/utils.c 157: Plugin version is not matching
Feb 12 15:33:56 desktop hpcups[5690]: prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 486: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
Feb 12 15:33:56 desktop hp[5691]: prnt/backend/hp.c 919: ERROR: null print job total=0
```

It looks like there's some issues there, but I'm not sure how to fix them. I've tried with Jetdirect and IPP and the hp protocol. I'm using an exact match driver from Hplip / foomatic when prompted for one (although one of the methods didn't ask for a driver). All produce the same results. What can I try?

Answer (score -1):

common/utils.c 69: unable to open /var/lib/hp/hplip.state

create hplip.state using root privilege and then install hp plugins you might need to this on your client/users machine if they are unable to give print.